# Full classes in Kelley's book

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Kelley's "General topology" (in the "Appendix") the *full classes* $X$ are defined as those with the property
$$
\forall A\in X\quad A\subseteq X.
$$
In the Russian translation it is added that this is equivalent to the property that the relation $\in$ is transitive on $X$:
$$
\forall A,B,C\in X\quad A\in B\in C \ \Rightarrow\ A\in C.
$$
I think there must be an easy trick for proving this equivalence, but I don't see it. Can anybody help me?

Comment: This is false; consider $\{\{0\}\}$; The second assertion is vacuously true but this set isn't transitive.

Comment: Ah, so $\{\{0\}\}$ satisfies the second condition, but not the first, does it?

Comment: Thanks to all for the help!

Comment: @CarlMummert , excuse me, I did not understand why the first condition implies the second. It is seen that $A\in X$, but why $A\in C$?

Comment: You are correct  - my eyes mentally "corrected" the formula in the question. The second formula should end with "$A \in X$" in order to be a consequence of the first formula.

Comment: So there are no implications between these conditions? Or still there is a trick for (1)$\Rightarrow$(2)?

Comment: Consider the example where $C = \{B\}$, $B = \{A\}$, $A = \emptyset$, and $X = \{A, B, C\}$. Then $X$ is transitive, because each element of $X$ is also a subset of $X$. But $A \not \in C$, so $X$ does not satisfy the second condition above. So it does seem that neither of the conditions above implies the other.

Comment: Carl, thank you! Pedro gave already a counterexample in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first property (the one you call "full class") is more commonly known as a **transitive** class/set in set theory.

It is not entirely uncommon to be confused by this name and get the misconception that this is the same as "a class on which the $\in$ relation is transitive" -- and apparently the translator thought this -- but that is not true, as Pedro's example $\{\{0\}\}$ shows.

Being transitive/full *is*, of course equivalent to
$$ \forall A, B[ A\in B\in X \Rightarrow A\in X \bigl] $$

Comment: Yes. Here's where I think the confusion happens. Being transitive can also be phrased as follows: make a directed graph $G_X$ whose nodes are sets: there is a node for $X$, a node for each element of $X$, a node for each element of an element of $X$, etc. and a directed edge from node $A$ to node $B$ if $A \in B$. Then $G_X$ is a DAG, and $X$ is a transitive set if and only if $G_X$ is transitively closed.  Thus the idea of a "transitive set" is not to make $\in$ a transitive relation on $X$ (that's wrong, as you say), but to make $G_X$ transitively closed - so "reachability" is transitive.

Comment: Henning, is there a counterexample for the reverse implication?

Answer (score 1):

I already posted one counterexample in the comment section. The one for the other direction is the following.

Intuitively, the class $V$ of all sets is transitive but it contains non transitive sets. So it is enough to get a “smaller” counterexample. For instance, $$
V_3=\mathcal{P}^3(\emptyset)=
\{0,\{0\},\{\{0\}\},\{0,\{0\}\}\}.
$$
The first three would do the job.

Comment: I've just realized that this is an example of the Reflection Theorem.